# How can I use a pattern for loading/refreshing like in the new Gmail app for android (using ActionBarSherlock)

Tags: design-patterns, gmail, actionbarsherlock, refresh, loading

I am using ActionBarSherlock and would like to know how can make my loading/refreshing animation pattern look alike the new Gmail app refresh:

[image]

Din.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris Banes made a library for just this purpose! It works with both the native action bar and ActionBarSherlock.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Comment: Ok.. this is nice and I will check this out... thanks Jake (I also use your libraries :))